# An unusual distributive property applied in a line integral

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, line-integrals

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Holditch's Theorem written by Arne Broman [here](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~troy/sflood/holditch.pdf). The proof of the generalization is really short and there is a single, important step that I don't get. In the words of the article, they use an "unusual" but legitimate operation of line integrals.

For context, they define $\alpha(t), \beta(t), \delta(t)$ the curves traced by the points $A,B$ and $D$ respectively. From their definitions, because the three points are in the same line with direction $\theta(t)$, we have two connections:
$$\delta(t) = \alpha(t)+a(\cos(\theta(t)), \sin(\theta(t)))$$
$$\beta(t) = \delta(t)+b(\cos(\theta(t)), \sin(\theta(t)))$$
So the first step of the proof is just writing $\beta$ with this expression, which changes a line integral from $\beta$ to $\delta$, I understand that. Now, the second step claims that:
$$\int_\delta  (x+b\cos\theta)d(y+b\sin\theta) = \int_\delta  x dy + b\int_\delta xd(\sin\theta)+b\int_\delta\cos \theta dy+b^2\int_\delta \cos\theta d(\sin\theta)$$

And I'm honestly really lost in this equality. It's like they're applying a distributive property with the integrand and the variable of integration, but I don't know what lets you do that. My intuition is that is just a consequence of the definition of the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral), but right now I don't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing unusual about the distributive property here. $d$ is linear, so $d(y+b\sin\theta) = dy + b\,d(\sin\theta)$. Now you just expand it out. You can plug in parametrizations and it will be the same:  If $\delta$ is parametrized by $(x(t),y(t))$, $a\le t\le b$, then you end up with
\begin{multline*}
\int_a^b \big(x(t)+b\cos\theta(t)\big)\big(y'(t)+b\cos\theta(t)\theta'(t)\big)\,dt = \int_a^b \big(x(t)y'(t) +bx(t)\cos\theta(t)\theta'(t)+b\cos(\theta(t))y'(t) + b^2\cos^2\theta(t)\theta'(t)\big)\,dt,
\end{multline*}
and now you break it up into four integrals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's the first time that I read about $d$ being an operator. Is this related with treating $d$ as a differential 1-form or something? I think in my courses we've always defined integration on curves and surfaces relating them with the parametrizations, so I would not know how to operate with $d(y+b\sin\theta)$, because it isn't a single variable. I didn't do the course on differential manifolds and forms though, is that neccesary to understand this?

Comment: No, it's certainly not necessary. In this context remember that everything is a function of $t$ once you parametrize (as I did in the answer), and if you have $f(t)$, then $df = f'(t)\,dt$. Of course, $d(f+g)=(f+g)'(t)\,dt = f'(t)\,dt + g'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: I'm sure you're right here, it's just that use of $df$ meaning $f'(t)dt$ is a bit foreign to me and I'm a bit confused. For example, would you say that (1) $\int_\beta x dy$ is equal to (2) $\int_a^b x(\beta(t)) y'(\beta(t)) dt$? In that case, what's the difference with (3) $\int_\beta x y' d\beta$? This third expression is how I would have written (2) as a line integral, with the notation I've seen until now.

Comment: Go back to any treatment of line integrals in a calculus course and it's what I said. Your (3) makes no sense. How do I know what $y'$ means without a parametrization? By the way, if you decide you want to learn about differential forms, you might consult my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try to see if I understand it a bit better with that.